# plotly text box filter in python

Tags: python, filter, plotly

I need to filter a plotly graph using a **text box filter**.

In the following example this would mean a text box, where one can type one or more **species names** (e.g. 'setosa') as a string - instead of click-selecting from the legend.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species",
                 size='petal_length', hover_data=['petal_width'])
fig.show()
```

Source: https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/

---

An implementation in R is shown here: https://plotly-r.com/interactives/filter-highlight.html
Code (see 16.2): https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html#selection-via-indirect-manipulation

Comment: Please show what you already tried to achieve this. The Plotly website has some examples of interactive filtering, like here: https://plotly.com/python/figurewidget-app/